# How should I interpret the analog switch states of the ADG788?

Tags: switches, analog

After reading the datasheet, this is how I interpret the switch states of the ADG788 analog switch:

[image]

This interpretation is based on the "Truth table" in the datasheet:

[image]

Nevertheless, it feels a bit counter-intuitive. It is weird that the B-poles are connected when the inputs are 0. Wouldn't it be more "intuitive" if the A-poles would be connected at input zero?
I'm a bit worried. It wouldn't be the first time a datasheet makes an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would not only be more intuitive if zero activated the first pole, but also more traditional (see the CD4053). And the ADG786 in the same datasheet works that way.

However, the datasheet is unambiguous, and explicitly shows in the image on page 1 that the ADG786 and ADG788 have opposite polarities:

[image: ADG786 ADG788 schematics]

Also, the datasheet got its fourth revision years ago, so it is extremely unlikely that this would be an error that somehow was not detected.

If this does not remove your doubts, you have to test it yourself.